# image gallery with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make an responsive image gallery with bootstrap, so that if you make the screen smaller, the images are still in there  right dimensions.

I try it like this:

```
<div id="tabs-2">


    <link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <ul class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
        {

            @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
            <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" height=150 width=200 /></li>
        }
    </ul>


</div>
```

But if you make the screen smaller the images are laying over each other.

So how to make this responsive?

Thank you

If I do it like this:

```
<div id="tabs-2">


    <link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container">

    @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos)
    {

        @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
                <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"><img src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt=""  /></li>
    </ul>
    }

    </div>

</div>
```

then all the images are under each other and not in a row.

and this is my css:

```
ul {         
          padding:0 0 0 0;
          margin:0 0 0 0;
      }
      ul li {     
          list-style:none;
          margin-bottom:25px;           
      }
      ul li img {
          cursor: pointer;
      }
```

see image[image]

Apparently this was doing the job:

Thank you all for your anwares

Comment: Remove height=150 & width=200 in img tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this library [LINK](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/)

Then do this assuming that your code is fetching images without errors this will work :

```
<div class="container" id="tabs-2">
    <link href="~/Content/ShowMoreImages.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LolaBikePhotos){

            @model  ContosoUniversity.Models.UserProfile
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="/Images/profile/@item.ImagePath" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

On your CSS add this :

```
.thumb{
   margin-top: 10px; //or whatever value you want.
}
```

Just make sure you put this after the library CSS so that it will work.

Comment: Hi Green, thank you, but one last thing the images are sticking now to each other not in the row dimension, but on the column dimension, I also have add the css.

Comment: Hi @hallohallo I made a little change would you mind trying it? Thanks.

Comment: The previous version of you was better, but still sticking on column height

Comment: Ok please use the previous version, just one favor, could you send a picture or screen shot of what's happening to the layout? Or Add some jsFiddle. Thanks.@hallohallo

Comment: Hi @hallohallo Now look at the answer. :) Hope it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77501/discussion-between-green-fox-and-hallo-hallo).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using bootstrap, remove the `height` and `width` from your `<img>` tag and add `'class= "img-responsive">`. Your images will resize according to the column width. Details here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 0):

Responsiveness works much better in fluid layout. To make that happen give height and width in % so that it automatic adjust according to screen (parent) width and height. For your example just remove the img width and height attribute and add `img-responsive` class and bootstrap will take care of it.

Without Bootstrap:
In general, give container width in % and image width and height according to parent. Like

```
<li class="imageContainer">
   <img class="imageStyle"></img>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.imageContainer{
   width:50%;
}
.imageStyle{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Use media queries for different device orientation.